# Elasticsearch sort based on multiple fields and then by random seed

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, random

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "example title 1",
        "priority": "high"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "example title 2",
        "priority": "high"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "example title 3",
        "priority": "high"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "example title 4",
        "priority": "low"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "title": "example title 5",
        "priority": "low"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "title": "example title 6",
        "priority": "low"
    }
]
```

I have the following items in my elasticsearch index and i can easily sort by multiple fields but i didnt find a way to sort by multiple fields and then random.

So, for example i would need to do this:

```
  "sort": [
    {
      "priority": "asc"
    },

    _script: {
        script: "Math.random() * 200000",
        type: "number",
        params: {},
        order: "asc"
    }

  ]
```

So, lets say on first query, you would get these results:

**3,2,1**(high priority comes first but randomized),**5,4,6**(low priority comes next, but also randomized)

Second query could also look like this:

**2,1,3**(high),**6,5,4**(low)

Answer (score 2):

Ughh, i guess you need to articulate a proper question before you can find a proper solution.

Anyway, here is the answer for all posterity:

```
{
  "size": 3,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "my_column1": "805"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "my_column2": "30"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "product_price": {
                  "gt": "500",
                  "lt": "1000"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "my_column3": "0"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "random_score": {
            "seed": "1477072619038"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "priority": "asc"
    },
    {
      "date_added": "asc"
    },
    {
      "_score": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how you mix function score with query filtering and multiple sorting using also random seed.